# JavaScript remove equivalent object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I'm writing a `d3 force graph` to make the update look fliud I implemented it like the [Modifying a Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) example. But unline in the example I want a dynamic updating behaviour. Given the situation I already called `initializeGraphData(json);` once, my `nodes`- array contains a set of `node` objects. On 2nd call I push every `json.nodes` object to the `nodes`- array. Then I get the difference between the `nodes`- array and the `json.nodes`- array. For each different object I want to remove it from the `nodes` array by giving in it's index and the parameter `1` to remove only one element.

```
function initializeGraphData(json){
    json.nodes.forEach(function(node){
        nodes.push(node);
    });
    json.links.forEach(function(link){
        links.push(link);
    });
    var difInNodes = nodes.diff(json.nodes);
    difInNodes.forEach(function(node){
        nodes.slice(nodes.indexOf(node), 1);
    });
    var difInLinks = links.diff(json.links);
    difInLinks.forEach(function(link){
        links.slice(links.indexOf(link), 1);
    });
    nodes.forEach(function(node){
        java.alert("In nodes array: " + node.name);
    });

    draw();
    checkForLinked(json);
    checkForOptions(json);
}
```

One node element might look like this

```
{"img":"ron.png","concept":null,"name":"Ron Weasley","id":1,"shortname":"Ron","properties":[{"property":"Animal","value":"Rat"}],"group":"#867b69"}
```

I do know that these are not the same objects when I try to remove them, so I thought I could use the `node.id` property, which didn't work as well.

```
var difInNodes = nodes.diff(json.nodes);
difInNodes.forEach(function(node){
   nodes.slice(node.id, 1);
});
```

How can I remove an object in an array that is equivalent by content to one in another array 1:1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) doesn't remove entries from the array, it creates a *new* array with a subset of the entries from the original.

Given where and how you're using it, I believe you meant to use [*`splice`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (with a `p`).

But you're also using `node.id` as though it were the index of the entry, which isn't likely to be correct (and certainly won't be correct after the first time you change the array). So first you need to find the right index, then use `splice` to remove the entry. ES2015 adds [`findIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312881/javascript-remove-equivalent-object-in-array/35312931#35312931) to the `Array.prototype` which is useful for finding the index of an entry based on a callback function; it can be shimmed/polyfilled on ES5 and earlier engines.

So:

```
var difInNodes = nodes.diff(json.nodes);
difInNodes.forEach(function(node){
   var index = nodes.findIndex(function(entry) { return entry.id == node.id; });
   if (index !== -1) {
     nodes.splice(node.id, 1);
     //     ^
   }
});
```

Alternately, you could use `Array#filter` to build a new array each time with only the entries you want:

```
var difInNodes = nodes.diff(json.nodes);
difInNodes.forEach(function(node){
   nodes = nodes.filter(function(entry) { return entry.id != node.id; });
});
```

Which you use is up to you, largely depending on what else will have a reference to the array (since the second method creates a *new* array).

Comment: Just `splice` instead of `slice` did the job regarding my first approach :) Thank you, I wasn't aware of this difference

Comment: Hit another problem. The `diff()` function tries to get the difference between the two arrays. But these two arrays don't hold the same reference to the JSON object- just the same values, so the diff function returns every object even if the objects are identical from content.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove a Object with: `array.splice(index,length);`

You just need to know the index of your object. Just loop through your array and check the index of the object you want to cut.

Something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
   if(array[i]["ID"] == yourobject["ID"]){
       array.splice(i,1);
   }
}
```